# Azure Hyperscale (Citus) couldn't create database with the citus account

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database, citus, azure-postgresql

After creating the Azure Hyperscale (Citus) on the Azure portal, I use DbBeaver to access to the created database. I can connect to that database (succeed login to with the `citus` account and its password on the Azure portal), but when I tried to create the new database, then I couldn't create it.

I have got the exception as below

[image]

After investigation a while, I found out that the `citus` account didn't have permission for `create database` as following

[image]

But I couldn't check that checkbox and save it. It has always thrown exception that I don't have permission with the `citus` account (the default account created after I created the Citus Postgres Db)

Just noticed that I can create the new database successfully with the same approach above in the last week. But now I couldn't.

Have anyone got the same issue as me? And how can we solve it? I tried to search around Google but have got no luck.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperscale (Citus) requires that users work on the default database (citus) and does not let users to create new databases.

The behavior has been always like this.

Could you tell about why you need a new database ?
If you need separation of the tables, you can use a namespace, if you need security you can set user based access levels on tables.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Murat for your clarifications. I just wonder why I could create a new database with Azure Hyperscale (Citus) before. There may be a bug in the Azure infrastructure.